# IndexOutOfBoundsException for MapView in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

I'm getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception when I try to update the adapter containing the `MapView`.

I'm using example [LiteListDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LiteListDemoActivity.java). Once it's static everything is fine, but when I want to submit an update to the adapter to show a different type of data not map related, then in some rare cases the app crashes.

The beginning of the stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:437)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.lite.u.a (u.java:4)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.lite.x.a (x.java:15)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.lite.j.onDraw (j.java:48)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:21860)
  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl (View.java:21129)
  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache (View.java:20989)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20705)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4535)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4507)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20688)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4535)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList (ViewGroup.java:4507)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20688)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:21586)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4326)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw (ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:20719)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:21586)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4551)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild (RecyclerView.java:4820)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4326)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:21863)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.draw (RecyclerView.java:4219)
```

Is it something related to the RecyclerView implementation? I am sharing the adapter from my code. You can find the full implementation in the link above that I shared.

```
/**
 * Adapter that displays a title and {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView} for each item.
 * The layout is defined in <code>lite_list_demo_row.xml</code>. It contains a MapView
 * that is programatically initialised in
 * {@link #(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)}
 */
private class MapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MapAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private NamedLocation[] namedLocations;

    private MapAdapter(NamedLocation[] locations) {
        super();
        namedLocations = locations;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.lite_list_demo_row, parent, false));
    }

    /**
     * This function is called when the user scrolls through the screen and a new item needs
     * to be shown. So we will need to bind the holder with the details of the next item.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder == null) {
            return;
        }
        holder.bindView(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return namedLocations.length;
    }

    /**
     * Holder for Views used in the {@link LiteListDemoActivity.MapAdapter}.
     * Once the  the <code>map</code> field is set, otherwise it is null.
     * When the {@link #onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)} callback is received and
     * the {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap} is ready, it stored in the {@link #map}
     * field. The map is then initialised with the NamedLocation that is stored as the tag of the
     * MapView. This ensures that the map is initialised with the latest data that it should
     * display.
     */
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        MapView mapView;
        TextView title;
        GoogleMap map;
        View layout;

        private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            layout = itemView;
            mapView = layout.findViewById(R.id.lite_listrow_map);
            title = layout.findViewById(R.id.lite_listrow_text);
            if (mapView != null) {
                // Initialise the MapView
                mapView.onCreate(null);
                // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
                mapView.getMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
            map = googleMap;
            setMapLocation();
        }

        /**
         * Displays a {@link LiteListDemoActivity.NamedLocation} on a
         * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap}.
         * Adds a marker and centers the camera on the NamedLocation with the normal map type.
         */
        private void setMapLocation() {
            if (map == null) return;

            NamedLocation data = (NamedLocation) mapView.getTag();
            if (data == null) return;

            // Add a marker for this item and set the camera
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(data.location, 13f));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(data.location));

            // Set the map type back to normal.
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }

        private void bindView(int pos) {
            NamedLocation item = namedLocations[pos];
            // Store a reference of the ViewHolder object in the layout.
            layout.setTag(this);
            // Store a reference to the item in the mapView's tag. We use it to get the
            // coordinate of a location, when setting the map location.
            mapView.setTag(item);
            setMapLocation();
            title.setText(item.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any update strategy in your adapter that you have shared on Github. The adapter takes a fixed-length array in the constructor and thus gets the size of the fixed array from the `getItemCount` function.

I would like to suggest modifying the adapter like the following.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * This shows to include a map in lite mode in a ListView.
 * Note the use of the view holder pattern with the
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback}.
 */
public class LiteListDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lite_list_demo);

        mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        // Set up the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

        // Pass the ArrayList instead of the array
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MapAdapter(getInitialLocations(LIST_LOCATIONS)));
        mRecyclerView.setRecyclerListener(mRecycleListener);
    }

    /**
     * Create a menu to switch between Linear and Grid LayoutManager.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lite_list_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.layout_linear:
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
                break;
            case R.id.layout_grid:
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Adapter that displays a title and {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView} for each item.
     * The layout is defined in <code>lite_list_demo_row.xml</code>. It contains a MapView
     * that is programatically initialised in
     * {@link #(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)}
     */
    private class MapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MapAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        // Take an ArrayList instead of array. Its easier to implement the add and clear functionality here
        private ArrayList<NamedLocation> namedLocations;

        private MapAdapter(ArrayList<NamedLocation> locations) {
            super();
            namedLocations = locations;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.lite_list_demo_row, parent, false));
        }

        /**
         * This function is called when the user scrolls through the screen and a new item needs
         * to be shown. So we will need to bind the holder with the details of the next item.
         */
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if (holder == null) {
                return;
            }
            holder.bindView(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return namedLocations.size();
        }

        public void updateLocationList(ArrayList<NamedLocation> newLocations) {

            // Clear the old locations
            this.namedLocations.clear();

            // Add the new locations passed by calling this function to the list associated with this adapter.
            for (NamedLocation location : newLocations) this.namedLocations.add(location);

            // Call notifyDataSetChanged so that the RecyclerView takes the new ArrayList to be populated in the RecyclerView 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        /**
         * Holder for Views used in the {@link LiteListDemoActivity.MapAdapter}.
         * Once the  the <code>map</code> field is set, otherwise it is null.
         * When the {@link #onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)} callback is received and
         * the {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap} is ready, it stored in the {@link #map}
         * field. The map is then initialised with the NamedLocation that is stored as the tag of the
         * MapView. This ensures that the map is initialised with the latest data that it should
         * display.
         */
        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {

            MapView mapView;
            TextView title;
            GoogleMap map;
            View layout;

            private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                layout = itemView;
                mapView = layout.findViewById(R.id.lite_listrow_map);
                title = layout.findViewById(R.id.lite_listrow_text);
                if (mapView != null) {
                    // Initialise the MapView
                    mapView.onCreate(null);
                    // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
                    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
                map = googleMap;
                setMapLocation();
            }

            /**
             * Displays a {@link LiteListDemoActivity.NamedLocation} on a
             * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap}.
             * Adds a marker and centers the camera on the NamedLocation with the normal map type.
             */
            private void setMapLocation() {
                if (map == null) return;

                NamedLocation data = (NamedLocation) mapView.getTag();
                if (data == null) return;

                // Add a marker for this item and set the camera
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(data.location, 13f));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(data.location));

                // Set the map type back to normal.
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            }

            private void bindView(int pos) {
                NamedLocation item = namedLocations.get(pos);
                // Store a reference of the ViewHolder object in the layout.
                layout.setTag(this);
                // Store a reference to the item in the mapView's tag. We use it to get the
                // coordinate of a location, when setting the map location.
                mapView.setTag(item);
                setMapLocation();
                title.setText(item.name);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * RecycleListener that completely clears the {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap}
     * attached to a row in the RecyclerView.
     * Sets the map type to {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap#MAP_TYPE_NONE} and clears
     * the map.
     */
    private RecyclerView.RecyclerListener mRecycleListener = new RecyclerView.RecyclerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
            MapAdapter.ViewHolder mapHolder = (MapAdapter.ViewHolder) holder;
            if (mapHolder != null && mapHolder.map != null) {
                // Clear the map and free up resources by changing the map type to none.
                // Also reset the map when it gets reattached to layout, so the previous map would
                // not be displayed.
                mapHolder.map.clear();
                mapHolder.map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Location represented by a position ({@link com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng} and a
     * name ({@link java.lang.String}).
     */
    private static class NamedLocation {

        public final String name;
        public final LatLng location;

        NamedLocation(String name, LatLng location) {
            this.name = name;
            this.location = location;
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<NamedLocation> getInitialLocations(NamedLocation[] locationsArray) {
        ArrayList<NamedLocation> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (NamedLocation location : locationsArray)
            locationArrayList.add(location);

        return locationArrayList;
    }

    /**
     * A list of locations to show in this ListView.
     */
    private static final NamedLocation[] LIST_LOCATIONS = new NamedLocation[]{
            new NamedLocation("Cape Town", new LatLng(-33.920455, 18.466941)),
            new NamedLocation("Beijing", new LatLng(39.937795, 116.387224)),
            new NamedLocation("Bern", new LatLng(46.948020, 7.448206)),
            new NamedLocation("Breda", new LatLng(51.589256, 4.774396)),
            new NamedLocation("Brussels", new LatLng(50.854509, 4.376678)),
            new NamedLocation("Copenhagen", new LatLng(55.679423, 12.577114)),
            new NamedLocation("Hannover", new LatLng(52.372026, 9.735672)),
            new NamedLocation("Helsinki", new LatLng(60.169653, 24.939480)),
            new NamedLocation("Hong Kong", new LatLng(22.325862, 114.165532)),
            new NamedLocation("Istanbul", new LatLng(41.034435, 28.977556)),
            new NamedLocation("Johannesburg", new LatLng(-26.202886, 28.039753)),
            new NamedLocation("Lisbon", new LatLng(38.707163, -9.135517)),
            new NamedLocation("London", new LatLng(51.500208, -0.126729)),
            new NamedLocation("Madrid", new LatLng(40.420006, -3.709924)),
            new NamedLocation("Mexico City", new LatLng(19.427050, -99.127571)),
            new NamedLocation("Moscow", new LatLng(55.750449, 37.621136)),
            new NamedLocation("New York", new LatLng(40.750580, -73.993584)),
            new NamedLocation("Oslo", new LatLng(59.910761, 10.749092)),
            new NamedLocation("Paris", new LatLng(48.859972, 2.340260)),
            new NamedLocation("Prague", new LatLng(50.087811, 14.420460)),
            new NamedLocation("Rio de Janeiro", new LatLng(-22.90187, -43.232437)),
            new NamedLocation("Rome", new LatLng(41.889998, 12.500162)),
            new NamedLocation("Sao Paolo", new LatLng(-22.863878, -43.244097)),
            new NamedLocation("Seoul", new LatLng(37.560908, 126.987705)),
            new NamedLocation("Stockholm", new LatLng(59.330650, 18.067360)),
            new NamedLocation("Sydney", new LatLng(-33.873651, 151.2068896)),
            new NamedLocation("Taipei", new LatLng(25.022112, 121.478019)),
            new NamedLocation("Tokyo", new LatLng(35.670267, 139.769955)),
            new NamedLocation("Tulsa Oklahoma", new LatLng(36.149777, -95.993398)),
            new NamedLocation("Vaduz", new LatLng(47.141076, 9.521482)),
            new NamedLocation("Vienna", new LatLng(48.209206, 16.372778)),
            new NamedLocation("Warsaw", new LatLng(52.235474, 21.004057)),
            new NamedLocation("Wellington", new LatLng(-41.286480, 174.776217)),
            new NamedLocation("Winnipeg", new LatLng(49.875832, -97.150726))
    };
}
```

Now you have the `updateLocationList` function in your adapter and when you need to change the location list, just use this function to pass your updated location list in your adapter.

Please note that I have not tested this code. So, it might have some compilation error as I have changed the array implementation to a list. Please modify as per your need.

Hope that helps!